# Compile and display PDF of individual slide in beamer presentation using Vim

Tags: vim, latex, beamer

I use Vim as my text editor and I quite like beamer as a slide presentation tool.
However, compiling a large beamer presentation can take a little bit of time (perhaps 10 or 20 seconds). 
This time is generally fine for a normal LaTeX document because the content often just works. In beamer slides, there are sometimes issues about how well the text fits on the slide. This is also true when a slide involves a more complex layout of graphics, text, and so on.

I'd like to set up a shortcut command using Vim that just compiles the active slide as a PDF (as defined by the cursor being between the relevant `frame` environment.

I realise that the preamble and several other features of the document can influence the exact formatting of the slide. However, I imagine an approximation would be sufficient. Perhaps it would be sufficient just to compile the preamble and the active slide.

Any suggestions would be most helpful.

Comment: It would be informative to us other users if you would vote for one or another of these as offering a workable solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a small function that does what you want (copies the preamble and current frame into a separate file and compiles it):

```
function! CompileCurrentSlide()
   let tmpfile = "current-slide.tex"
   silent! exe '1,/\s*\\begin{document}/w! '.tmpfile
   silent! exe '.+1?\\begin{frame}?,.-1/\\end{frame}/w! >> '.tmpfile
   silent! exe '/\s*\\end{document}/w! >> '.tmpfile
   silent! exe '!pdflatex -halt-on-error '.tmpfile.' >/dev/null'
endfunction
" 
noremap <silent><buffer> zz :silent call <SID>CompileCurrentSlide()<CR>
```

Pressing zz will compile whatever frame the cursor is in and put the output in "current-slide.pdf".  You can replace -halt-on-error with whatever other option you'd like.  The script doesn't open a separate window, like the function in the previous answer; you just continue to edit the main file.  I'm not a vim expert so there may be better ways to do this, but the above has worked fine for me in the creation of several Beamer presentations.

Answer (score 1):

The following function should create a new temporary file with only the preamble and the current frame. It opens up the file in a split, and from that point onward, you should be able to compile that file alone and use whatever program you do for viewing it. I don't know a lot about tex and even less about beamer, so you may have to tweak this to better fit your needs.

```
function! CompileBeamer()
  " Collect the lines for the current frame:
  let frame = []
  if searchpair('\\begin{frame}', '', '\\end{frame}', 'bW') > 0
    let frame = s:LinesUpto('\\end{frame}')
    call add(frame, getline('.')) " add the end tag as well
  endif

  " Go to the start, and collect all the lines up to the first "frame" item.
  call cursor(1, 1)
  let preamble = s:LinesUpto('\\begin{frame}')

  let body = preamble + frame

  " Open up a temporary file and put the selected lines in it.
  let filename = tempname().'.tex'
  exe "split ".filename
  call append(0, body)
  set nomodified
endfunction

function! s:LinesUpto(pattern)
  let line = getline('.')
  let lines = []

  while line !~ a:pattern && line('.') < line('$')
    call add(lines, line)
    call cursor(line('.') + 1, 1)
    let line = getline('.')
  endwhile

  return lines
endfunction
```